# Rails 4 associations display name and not ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I display a name and not the ID? It must be so simple, but it ain't working.

Models:

```
class CyclingTeam < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :riders
end

class Rider < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cycling_team
  belongs_to :country

  has_many :tour_teams
end

class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :riders
end
```

Then I have a View:

```
<tr>  
<td><%= rider.name %></td>  
<td><%= rider.birthday %></td>  
<td><%= rider.country.name %></td>  
<% if current_user.try(:admin?) %>  
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_rider_path(rider) %></td>  
<% end %>  
</tr>
```

The forms are working, but a simple view isn't.Can anyone help? thanks.

Extra:

```
class RidersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_rider, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /riders
  # GET /riders.json

def index
    @riders = Rider.all
    @rider = Country.all
   end

  # GET /riders/1
  # GET /riders/1.json
  def show
    @riders = Rider.all
    @rider = Country.all  
  end

 # GET /riders/new
  def new
   @rider = Rider.new
 end

  private
   # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_rider
      @rider = Rider.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def rider_params
       params.require(:rider).permit(:name, :birthday, :tdf, :allround, :climber,      :sprinter, :classic, :yellow, :green, :white, :polka, :cycling_team__attributes => [:id, :name], :country_attributes => [:id, :name])
    end
end
```

hope it helps.

Comment: name in where to display.

Comment: I see no `code` for `id` in the `view`.Which `id` you are talking about?

Comment: Please post the `full code` of your `view`.

Comment: It's the rider.country_id reference. I want to show the country name instead of the id. If I just put rider.country in the view I get something like #<Country:0x0000010300c130>.

Comment: You already have this line `<%= rider.country.name %>` which gives you the name of the country

Comment: I get a: NoMethodError at /cycling_teams/1
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Post your `controller code` and `full error stack` And also `full code` of your `view page`

Comment: I guess it fails if there is no country associated? write `<%= rider.country.nil? ? 'Unknown' : rider.country.name %>`

Comment: rider controller added.

Comment: Why you have `@country.all`? the error is because of that.It should be `Country.all`

Comment: No changed it, didn't work.

Comment: I also have a error: Request parameters 
{"action"=>"show", "controller"=>"cycling_teams", "id"=>"1"}. Why do I need the cycling teams_id? BTW it's the complete view I posted. and still getting: NoMethodError at /cycling_teams/1
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Please post your full error stack.

Comment: {:rider=>#<Rider id: 2, name: "tets", birthday: "1986-05-19", tdf: false, allround: false, climber: false, sprinter: false, classic: false, yellow: false, green: false, white: false, polka: false, cycling_team_id: 1, country_id: nil, created_at: "2014-05-19 11:38:51", updated_at: "2014-05-19 11:38:51">, :rider_counter=>1}

Comment: and maybe this is easier: https://github.com/bamboowebcare/testtour

Comment: have you updated your question with the fixed, working code?  Because it says `rider.country.name` now.  If so then that's really confusing, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: @Uri Agassi: Thanks, works fine now

Answer (score 0):

This isn't right...

```
  def show
    @riders = Rider.all
    @rider = Country.all  
  end
```

You are setting the instance variable @rider to equal an array of all countries which is overriding what your `set_rider` method is doing. You're also setting @riders to all riders, which you don't need on the show page.

As an alternative.. on your Rider model create a method...

```
country_name
  self.country.name if self.country
end
```

in your controller do nothing in show...

```
def show
end
```

... and you can output @rider.country_name in your view.

```
<%= @rider.country_name %>
```

Comment: My pleasure, I hope it was helpful in sorting your problem.